# Call Authenticator Microservice From ApiGateway ServerSecurityContextRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

**Introduction**

I have a microservice responsible for authenticating each API call to my server. so when any request comes API gateway is supposed to call the authenticator for the validation with token and after this is a success the actual API call process to the intended destination.

API Gateway is a `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` project using `spring-boot-starter-webflux`. And the other microservice can be connected using `FeignClient`.

**Problem**

I am trying to call the feignclient method from the `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` `authenticate()`. and I need some kind of possibility to intercept it and validate this to either throw error or return a success mono.

**But as of now the flatmap is not being called.**

**Code**

```
    import com.atlpay.pgapigateway.JwtAuthenticationToken
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl
    import org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ServerSecurityContextRepository
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
    import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange
    import reactor.core.publisher.Mono


    @Component
    class SecurityContextRepository : ServerSecurityContextRepository {

        @Autowired
        private lateinit var authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager

        override fun save(swe: ServerWebExchange, sc: SecurityContext): Mono<Void> {
            return Mono.empty()
        }

        override fun load(serverWebExchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<SecurityContext> {
            val path = serverWebExchange.request.path

            //send request to authentication manager
            val auth: Authentication = JwtAuthenticationToken(
                "",
                serverWebExchange.request.method!!.name,
                path.toString(),
                serverWebExchange.request.headers
            )

            return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(auth)
                .map { authentication ->
                    SecurityContextImpl(authentication)
                }
        }
    }
```

The above `SecurityContextRepository` calls the `AuthenticationManager` mentioned below.

```
    import com.atlpay.pgapigateway.JwtAuthenticationToken
    import com.atlpay.pgjavacontracts.feign.TestFeign
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
    import reactor.core.publisher.Mono


    @Component
    class AuthenticationManager : ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

        @Autowired
        private lateinit var testFeign: TestFeign

        override fun authenticate(authentication: Authentication): Mono<Authentication> {
            val authToken = (authentication as JwtAuthenticationToken).token
            val toReturnUserNamePasswordAuthenticationToken = JwtAuthenticationToken(
                authentication.token,
                authentication.httpMethod,
                authentication.path,
                authentication.httpHeaders
            )

            return testFeign.getUsers()
                .flatMap { response ->
                    //if error throw error
            >>>>>>  println("This is just a test >> ${response.status()}")
                    Mono.just(toReturnUserNamePasswordAuthenticationToken as Authentication)
                }
                .then(Mono.just(toReturnUserNamePasswordAuthenticationToken as Authentication))
        }
    }
```

From the above class I am expecting to intercept the call the validate the response code of the feignclient. at this line -

`println("This is just a test >> ${response.status()}")`

But this is never called!!

FeignClient is just a mock api for testing -

```
    import feign.Response
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
    import reactivefeign.spring.config.ReactiveFeignClient
    import reactor.core.publisher.Mono


    @ReactiveFeignClient(url = "https://630369f20de3cd918b34e39e.mockapi.io", name = "testFeign")
    interface TestFeign {
        @PostMapping("/users")
        fun getUsers(): Mono<Response>
    }
```

**Attempts**

Tried to make a call using Restclient blocking api. and got the result.

but I want it to be load balanced so changed to a `LoadBalanced` rest client and used the URL 'http://myMicroServiceName/validate' this gives me a `block()/blockfirst()/blocklast() are blocking` error.

So this is out of scope for now.

I think I am missing some basic structure in the Reactive part or its an issue with the Apigateway `ReactiveAuthenticationManager`.

**Update**
Found an solution with [webfilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebFilter.html). will update with an answer soon.

Any suggestion is appreciated.